# maxima: How to transform a symbolic matrix by specific variables

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, transformation, maxima, factorization

In maxima I have calculated a complicated 2x2 matrix, let's call it "HUGE" and it has 8 variables in it:

```
a, b, c, d, tr11, tr12, tr21, tr22
```

This is not correct syntax, but just to illustrate:

Given

```
HUGE(a,b,c,d,tr11,tr12,tr21,tr22)=matrix([0,0],[0,0])
```

I want to factorize/transform it into

```
HUGE_NEW(a,b,c,d)=matrix([tr11,tr21],[tr12,tr22])
```

By writing things like HUGE_NEW(a,b,c,d) I mean a new matrix that contains variables a,b,c,d only.

In other words I want to say something like

```
solve (HUGE - matrix([tr11,tr21],[tr12,tr22]) = matrix([0,0],[0,0]), [a, b, c, d], [tr11, tr12, tr21, tr22])
```

How can I go about it? My matrix is really complicated, so doing it with pen and paper is not an option.

In case someone asks for the actual value of my HUGE-matrix to try it out:

```
HUGE: matrix([−(sqrt(d^2−2*a*d+4*b*c+a^2)*((b*d+a*b)*tr12*tr22+(−d^2−a*d)*tr12*tr21+(−b*d−a*b)*tr11*tr12+(d^2+a*d)*tr11^2)+(b*d^2+2*b^2*c+a^2*b)*tr12*tr22+((−2*b*c−a^2)*d−d^3)*tr12*tr21+(b*d^2+2*b^2*c+a^2*b)*tr11*tr12+((−2*b*c−a^2)*d−d^3)*tr11^2)/(2*a*d−2*b*c),−(sqrt(d^2−2*a*d+4*b*c+a^2)*((b*d+a*b)*tr22^2+(−d^2−a*d)*tr21*tr22+((−b*d−a*b)*tr12+(d^2+a*d)*tr11)*tr21)+(b*d^2+2*b^2*c+a^2*b)*tr22^2+((−2*b*c−a^2)*d−d^3)*tr21*tr22+((b*d^2+2*b^2*c+a^2*b)*tr12+((−2*b*c−a^2)*d−d^3)*tr11)*tr21)/(2*a*d−2*b*c)],[(sqrt(d^2−2*a*d+4*b*c+a^2)*((a*d+a^2)*tr12*tr22+(−c*d−a*c)*tr12*tr21+(−a*d−a^2)*tr11*tr12+(c*d+a*c)*tr11^2)+(a*d^2+2*a*b*c+a^3)*tr12*tr22+(−c*d^2−2*b*c^2−a^2*c)*tr12*tr21+(a*d^2+2*a*b*c+a^3)*tr11*tr12+(−c*d^2−2*b*c^2−a^2*c)*tr11^2)/(2*a*d−2*b*c),(sqrt(d^2−2*a*d+4*b*c+a^2)*((a*d+a^2)*tr22^2+(−c*d−a*c)*tr21*tr22+((−a*d−a^2)*tr12+(c*d+a*c)*tr11)*tr21)+(a*d^2+2*a*b*c+a^3)*tr22^2+(−c*d^2−2*b*c^2−a^2*c)*tr21*tr22+((a*d^2+2*a*b*c+a^3)*tr12+(−c*d^2−2*b*c^2−a^2*c)*tr11)*tr21)/(2*a*d−2*b*c)])
```

**Edit:**

When I do this:

```
solve(HUGE = matrix([0,0],[0,0]),[tr11,tr12,tr21,tr11]);
```

maxima returns:

```
[]
```

I also tried:

```
solve([
−(sqrt(d^2−2*a*d+4*b*c+a^2)*((b*d+a*b)*tr12*tr22+(−d^2−a*d)*tr12*tr21+(−b*d−a*b)*tr11*tr12+(d^2+a*d)*tr11^2)+(b*d^2+2*b^2*c+a^2*b)*tr12*tr22+((−2*b*c−a^2)*d−d^3)*tr12*tr21+(b*d^2+2*b^2*c+a^2*b)*tr11*tr12+((−2*b*c−a^2)*d−d^3)*tr11^2+2*a^2*d−2*a*b*c)/(2*a*d−2*b*c)=0,
−(sqrt(d^2−2*a*d+4*b*c+a^2)*((b*d+a*b)*tr22^2+(−d^2−a*d)*tr21*tr22+((−b*d−a*b)*tr12+(d^2+a*d)*tr11)*tr21)+(b*d^2+2*b^2*c+a^2*b)*tr22^2+((−2*b*c−a^2)*d−d^3)*tr21*tr22+((b*d^2+2*b^2*c+a^2*b)*tr12+((−2*b*c−a^2)*d−d^3)*tr11)*tr21+2*a*c*d−2*b*c^2)/(2*a*d−2*b*c)=0,
(sqrt(d^2−2*a*d+4*b*c+a^2)*((a*d+a^2)*tr12*tr22+(−c*d−a*c)*tr12*tr21+(−a*d−a^2)*tr11*tr12+(c*d+a*c)*tr11^2)+(a*d^2+2*a*b*c+a^3)*tr12*tr22+(−c*d^2−2*b*c^2−a^2*c)*tr12*tr21+(a*d^2+2*a*b*c+a^3)*tr11*tr12+(−c*d^2−2*b*c^2−a^2*c)*tr11^2−2*a*b*d+2*b^2*c)/(2*a*d−2*b*c)=0,
(sqrt(d^2−2*a*d+4*b*c+a^2)*((a*d+a^2)*tr22^2+(−c*d−a*c)*tr21*tr22+((−a*d−a^2)*tr12+(c*d+a*c)*tr11)*tr21)+(a*d^2+2*a*b*c+a^3)*tr22^2+(−c*d^2−2*b*c^2−a^2*c)*tr21*tr22+((a*d^2+2*a*b*c+a^3)*tr12+(−c*d^2−2*b*c^2−a^2*c)*tr11)*tr21−2*a*d^2+2*b*c*d)/(2*a*d−2*b*c)=0
],[tr11,tr12,tr21,tr22]);
```

which results in an error:

```
Polynomial quotient is not exact
 -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your equations have sqrt in them. Try the `to_poly_solve` package for that. i.e. `load(to_poly_solve);` and then `to_poly_solve([HUGE[1,1] = 0, HUGE[1,2] = 0, HUGE[2,1] = 0, HUGE[2,2] = 0], [tr11, tr12, tr21, tr22]);`

When I try that, I get several messy expressions as a result. I didn't check to see if they are correct solutions. Good luck, have fun, let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks! Hm... When I run the code my computer sounds like a vacuum cleaner (CPU works hard). How long did it take for you to obtain the result? I'm going to let it run for a while, but it seems it never to finishes. I use maxima 5.32.1

Comment: I am working with 5.39. My advice is to update your installation. There have been many bug fixes and other improvements since 5.32.

Comment: Newer versions seem not to support mouse selection of parts of the formulas, which is very important to me, so I decided to stick with the old version. So it's not really solved for me but it may have been if I updated, so I'm going to accept.